# Custom Search Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, microsoft-outlook-2016

I am trying to create a custom search that finds the following:

Flagged Emails & Unread

I have been able to do one or the other, but not both.  It's strange because it did work for the past 2 years, but after changing my email address it stopped.

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

Step 1: Select "Only items that are: unread" under **More Choices** tab:

[image]

Step 2: Select "Follow Up Flag" "is not empty" under **Advanced** tab.

[image]